# Postioning of a clickable dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a mobile first approach to create a responsive website. I'm currently working on my navigation menu and I'm satisfied with it on mobile (though it's far from perfect). However, when styling my navigation menu for web use I'm not able to position my dropdown content below the element in my menu. It's currently popping up in the upper left corner.

I'm using jQuery to create my clickable menu (don't know if that's relevant).

I also experience a bug on mobile where i cannot close the dropdown after opening it again. If anyone has an answer for that too, that would be great but I'm satisfied with it for now.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: You are required to post your code within your question and not any third party site: [mcve]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not a perfect example, but you are best off removing your use of floating and replacing with a display led approach.

Something along these lines:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    nav > a, .dropNav, nav > div {
        display: inline;
        position: relative;
    }

    .dropList {
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
        padding-left: 0;
    }
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/davcpas123/mjukghz6/1/

This will achieve something similar to this:
[image]